# How to bind events to my gridview code (which extends from CGridView)

Tags: yii

I wrote a Class MyGridView extends from the CGridView.
MyGridView will automaticlly generate two buttons in the header, 
one is a pdf icon, another is a excel icon. but how can I bind event to this two icon? 
so that I can use my code to generate PDF or EXCEL for this CGridView based on the dataprovider and columns.

the PDF export code and the EXCEL export code are all ready, I just don't know how to bind server-side event for the Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this depends a lot on your code to generate the PDF and EXCEL files, there are several ways to "bind" those buttons to generate the files.

1. In the same action that renders the grid view in the first place
2. different actions that use the same code base that generates the CDataProvider.

for the first case, you can pass a parameter to the action that tells it to generate the corresponding file:

```
<?php 
public function actionIndex()
{
  //Code base to generate the CActiveData provider.

  //Check if we are asking for the PDF version
  if(isset($_GET["pdf"])){
    //Your code to generate the PDF
  }elseif (isset($_GET["excel"])) {
    //Your code to generate the EXCEL
  }else{
    //render the view with the Grid
  }
}

 ?>
```

Then in your MyGridClass, just point your buttons to the corresponding url:

```
//For the pdf
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('', array('pdf' => '1'));
//For the excel
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('', array('excel' => '1'));
```

You can adjust this to have 2 separate actions if you want.

Comment: I can get the dataprovider and the columns, why do I need to write code in the controller? I find a way to do this code. I overwrite the CGridView run function then I put the PDF and Excel code in it. then no code in the cotroller, that means if others use this code, then he don't need to write code in the controller to export. anyway thanks for your reply.